# accessing service's property through multiple components in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have property that is calculated in the component 1 and i am using service to access and store that property and access that property value from another component however the value is not reflected in another component . i am doing something wrong

**component 1**

```
 import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrosspropertiesService } from "../services/Crossproperties.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css'],
  providers:[CrosspropertiesService]
})
export class TimerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private crossproperties: CrosspropertiesService) { }
  public projectheader: number = 959 ;//lets assume
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.projectheader = this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth;
    console.log(this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth);// console has value 959
    }

  }

}
```

**component 2**

```
    import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { CrosspropertiesService } from "../../services/Crossproperties.service";
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-projects',
      templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css'],
      providers:[CrosspropertiesService]
    })
    export class ProjectsComponent implements AfterViewInit {

      constructor(private crossproperties: CrosspropertiesService ) { }

      public headerWidth :number;
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.headerWidth= this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth;
        console.log(this.headerWidth); //console has value undefined 
      }
```

**and service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class CrosspropertiesService {
  public projectHeaderWidth:number;
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Are these components loading as sibling routes? If parent route is different  your app will reload and memory will be lost

Comment: And in Component 1, how is `this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth` giving 959? shouldn't the expression be : `this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth = this.projectheader`?

Comment: And Yes, that what @yurzui has mentioned

Comment: um yes that should be `this.crossproperties.projectHeaderWidth = this.projectheader` thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add service to `providers` array on component, each components gets its own instance service.

Remove `providers` property from component and add it to parent component or `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [CrosspropertiesService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: yes at first i put the service to providers in ngmodule but it compiles with warning saying `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic`
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:

Comment: Check your imports. Always use lower-case like `cross-properties.service` See also https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/926